# How do i setup grpc with SSL in .net

Tags: .net, ssl, protocol-buffers, grpc

How do i get server side authentication up and running for grpc in .net?
Been generating certs and trying different setups now for a while and i am getting tired. Works fine without SSL.

This is the last try i made, giving me error

```
Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Connect Failed"
```

Certs like this

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -key server.key -out server.crt -days 3650
```

Server

```
        const int port = 50052;

        var serverimpl= new Server
        {
            Services =
            {
                TestServer.BindService(new TestServerImpl())
            },
            Ports =
            {
                new ServerPort("localhost", port, new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair>
                {
                    new KeyCertificatePair
                    (
                       File.ReadAllText(@"server.crt"),
                       File.ReadAllText(@"server.key")
                    )
                }))
            }
        };
        serverimpl.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Test server listening on port " + port);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the server...");
        Console.ReadKey();

        serverimpl.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
```

Client

```
        var channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1", 50052, new SslCredentials(File.ReadAllText("server.crt")));
        var client = new TestServer.TestServiceClient(channel);



        var result = client.TestCall(new Query
        {    
            From = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-10).Ticks,
            To = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks
        });

        channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to read-up on open-ssl usage, this will generate working certs, the code was fine.

```
openssl req \
   -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key \
   -x509 -days 365 -out domain.crt
```

some easy to read how-to

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs